# Datatable getting row id and putting it to link in every cell

Tags: datatables

I have problem getting row id and putting it into links in every cell.
Id I'm getting from mysql db and then encoded to json.

Here is response got from debug console:

{"data":[["10501","BBBB AB (publ):8999","452075","BBBB 20 BOX 17","ASKERSUND","ASKERSUN","xDSL koppar","Small",null,"10.50.1.0/24","Details</a>"],

["10502","BBBB AB (publ):8999","452026","AAAA 11","LAX\u00c5","LAX\u00c5","xDSL koppar","Small",null,"10.50.2.0/24","Details</a>"],

["10503","BBB AB (publ):8999","166201","AAAAA 1 BOX 193","AVESTA","AVESTAMT","SWEFX2/4/8","Small",null,"10.50.3.0/24","Details</a>"]...

Datable init code:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                                      "aProcessing": true,
                                      "aServerSide": true,
                                      "ajax": "index.php?ajax",
                                          "columnDefs": [ {
                                           "targets": 11,
                                           "render": function ( data, type, meta ) {
                                                      return '<a target="_blank" href="add_device.php?rowid="'+data+'" class="btn btn-md btn-success">Add new device</a>';
                                           }
                                       }]
                            });
```

It generate links but without id, just add_device.php?rowid=.

I tried to add "data": data, but console show me "data is undefined"

Can anyone help me with that ?

Answer (score 0):

Оccasionally I found a problem. Just changed href link to:

```
href="add_device.php?rowid=' + data[0] + '" class="btn btn-md btn-success">Add new device</a>';
```